# Почему php выдает эту ошибку?

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$content_width' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/u0665743/data/www/hqherb.ru/wp-content/themes/digitalworld/functions.php on line 1

```
<?phpif ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 900;if( !class_exists('Digitalworld_Functions') ){    class Digitalworld_Functions{protected static $instance = null; public function __construct() {            add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array($this,'settup') );            add_action( 'widgets_init', array($this,'widgets_init') );            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'scripts') );            add_filter( 'get_default_comment_status', array($this,'open_default_comments_for_page'), 10, 3 );            add_action('init',array($this,'add_muti_widgets'));            $this->includes();        }        public  function settup(){      load_theme_textdomain( 'digitalworld', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

Comment: Вы думаете кто-то будет разбираться в однострочном коде?

Answer (score 2):

`<?php if` и `<?phpif` - две большие разницы.

`<?php if` - это начало PHP кода с последующим ключевым словом `if`

`<?phpif` - зависит от настройки [`short_open_tag`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). Это либо вовсе не PHP код и PHP его обрабатывать не будет никак (при выключенном `short_open_tag`). Либо это начало PHP кода `<?` и затем слово `phpif`. Например, это может быть именем вызываемой функции и потому не вызывает ошибку само по себе. Но вот дальше по синтаксису уже получается невозможная ситуация, что и порождает ошибку. Сообщение об ошибке синтаксиса может только сказать, где у парсера не осталось возможных вариантов интерпретации написанного. Ошибка может быть ранее.

По синтаксису после открывающего тега `<?php` пробельный символ [стоять должен](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.3/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l#L1975).

Comment: по моему тут просто линуксовые переносы строки съелись при вставке кода сюда. там и последующие места, где напрашиваются переносы строк отсутствуют.

Comment: @teran, тогда бы в ошибке не про `line 1` было

Comment: действительно, упустил из виду. но по крайней мере это вариант событий, приведший к такой ошибке. вряд ли это какой то минифакатор, ибо далее пробельные отступы сохранены, а пропали только новые строки.

Comment: да, тут согласен. Скорей всего это действительно изначально криво скопированный код.